# Tasker (Android) Automation : Designing a profile

Tags: android, automation, tasker

I am a bit of a noob when it come to handling **tasker**.
I have two queries.

1.I want a profile active only between **9 AM to 11:30 AM on sundays**. Not any other day.
 I was able to do this for the required time, or the day but not specific time of a specific day

2.If I want a location specific profile, should I be present at the location to be able to design the profile? Will I be able to do this from my home, say. I need a profile for my college , which is kinda far away. How do I do this profile from my home. (I tried state using Wifi, but that wouldn't be specific to only location). **And this profile needs to be active on weekdays.**

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

location can be gained in multiple ways...

Profile state Location > New Location
You can then set locations and name them
As said above you can simply 'navigate' to the location in the map, or click the button to store your current location.
You can also choose how the device finds your location:
GPS, NET (cell data) or BOTH

Another method would be location based on WiFi near or connected.

Profile state
Net > Wifi Near or WiFi connected.

You can then click them agnifying glass to select the current connected network, or those from a recent scan.

Another method would be Cell near
Profile state
Phone > Cell near
You can then scan for near cell towers, and have the profile activate when the device is near the desired cell towers.
Although i personally do not find this method particularly reliable.

Regarding specific time or days, long click the exisiting context and select 'another'
and choose day...you can then select whcih days
You can do this again to select a time

Answer (score 0):

Wow, such things are a very basics when using tasker.

You can add multiple triggers to your profile - just touch and hold the trigger and youll see "add" option. Selecting it will open menu with additional triggers to select.

As to choosing a GPS location as a trigger - that is available straight away when creating a profile, just scroll the map to desired place and set the trigger radius (it is better to use radius than pin-point location due to the nature of how GPS works)